# Present Simple vs Future Simple

Tags: grammar, tense

How to understand what tense construction must be used in the following case:

> He goes to London the next week.

Present simple is used, because it is plans for the next week.

But why we cannot say

> He'll go to London the next week.

Have a point of the sentence changed?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all, but I'll go by the title and presume you're asking about the difference between ways the future tense can be expressed. This question  [The usage of the present simple for the future actions](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/7092/2818) and [StoneyB's answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/7095/2818) probably answer your question.  In either case it's "next week" with no definite article ("the").

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because of the contraction, it makes it less formal, but the "the" in there is formal in a sentence that should be informal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you improve your answer to provide an example of such formal way using?

Comment: Absolutely. It's a mixture of formal and informal use. The formal version of saying that sentence would be "He will be going to London within the next week." - this would be used in a case of uncertainty as to the date of departure. "She has gone to London in the past week."

Comment: The definite article should not be used in either sentence proposed by OP, it's just "next week" whether simple present or future with will.

Answer (score 1):

Either usage is possible as well as the use of the auxiliary phrase "going to" or the present continuous:
He goes...
He will go...(He'll go...)
He is going to go...
He is going
Arguably the simple present and the present continuous speak with more certainty about the arrangements than do the modal (future) or the "going to" constructs. Otherwise, the options are equally valid grammatically and equally idiomatic, perhaps slightly less for the modal usage.

And idiomatic English does not mean the same thing by "the next week" and "next week".  "The next week" is idiomatic ONLY in reference to a previously designated (future) time.  For example, "Thanksgiving is the 4th Thursday in November. We go on vacation the next week."